# Nginx, ReactJS with Django Architecture

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx

I'm new to this technology.

Can anyone explain how the Architecture works ?.

1. Where the user request will hit first, to Nginx or React or Django. How to implement a great Architecture ?.
2. What are the good APIs use in between for better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell. For more details kindly dive deep into each technology.

[image]